# Trouble "overriding" values in a Groovy closure with .delegate

Tags: groovy, delegates, closures

I'd like to call a closure with a delegate parameter to override or shadow the calling context.  But the following example prints prints "outside" where I expect "inside".

**What am I doing wrong?**

```
def f(String a){

  def v = { return a }
  v.delegate = [a:"inside"]

  // Makes no difference:
  // v.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST

  println(v.call())
}

f("outside")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is that when the closure is declared inside the function, it 'closes' round the known values in the method (`a`), so that value becomes effectively hard-coded into the closure (it never hits the delegate to find the unknown value as it is known to the Closure).

If you move the closure `v` definition outside of the function `f`, then it works:

```
v = { return a }

def f(String a){
  v.delegate = [a:"inside"]
  println(v.call())
}

f("outside")
```

Answer (score 1):

Other option is to use `getProperty('a')` instead of directly using `a` as this forces the use of the delegate to retrieve the value of `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Can also be done by referring the `delegate` in the closure. For `v` as a closure, `a` does not make any sense (equivalent to use of ExpandoMetaClass)

```
def f(String a){
  def v = { delegate.a }
  v.delegate = [a:"inside"]

  println v()
}

f("outside")
```